# *ngIf Angular4 issue

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to work on a block of code where I can use *ngif else in introduced recently, I am hoping to see "system has no alerts" when alerts is None. Can some please explain to me what I am doing wrong. Any comment would be really helpful.

```
<ul class="al-msg-center clearfix">
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href class="dropdown-toggle" id="msg-dd1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
        <i (click)="refreshAlerts()" class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
        <span *ngIf="alerts.length">{{alerts.length}} </span>

        <div class="notification-ring"></div>
    </a>

    <div class="top-dropdown-menu dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="msg-dd1">
        <i class="dropdown-arr"></i>
        <div class="msg-list">
            <div *ngIf="alerts; else noAlerts">
                <a *ngFor="let msg of alerts" href class="clearfix">
                    <div class="msg-area">
                        <div>{{ msg.message }}</div>
                        <span>{{ msg.level }}</span>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <ng-template #noAlerts>
                <div class="msg-area">
                    <div>"The system has no alerts"</div>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With current code as soon as `alerts` exists, it will try to display content without looking at how much element `alerts` array has.

You should check `alerts.length` to get accurate result.

```
*ngIf="alerts?.length; else noAlerts"
```

Comment: @VaibhavChauhan glad to help you, Thanks :)